# Find rows matching only one of two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have two tables, `LatestOrders` and `Orders`, both have – amongst others – two columns, `OrderId` and `OrderItemId`.

Each `OrderId` has one or more `OrderItemId`s to it, like so:

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemId |
+---------+-------------+
| 5062154 |      187503 |
| 5063171 |      188697 |
| 5063670 |      189314 |
| 5063670 |      189315 |
+---------+-------------+
```

As you can see, while **5062154** and **5063171** have only one `OrderItemId`, **5063670** has two.

I'm trying to find all `OrderItemId`s in the `Orders` table that their `OrderId` is also in the `LatestOrders` table but with no matching `OrderItemId`.

So, as an example, say the above table is the `Orders` table, and below is the `LatestOrders` table:

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemId |
+---------+-------------+
| 5062154 |      187503 |
| 5063171 |      188697 |
| 5063670 |      189314 |
| 5063698 |      189401 |
+---------+-------------+
```

I’ll need **189315** as the result, because the `OrderId` is in the `Orders` table, but its `OrderItemId` is not.

I'm able to get a list of all those `OrderId`s with the query below, but I can't seem to find how to manipulate this to return the `OrderItemId`s.

```
WITH cte1
     AS (
     SELECT OrderId
          , COUNT(OrderId) AS Count
     FROM Orders
     GROUP BY OrderId),
     cte2
     AS (
     SELECT OrderId
          , COUNT(OrderId) AS Count
     FROM LatestOrders
     GROUP BY OrderId)
     SELECT *
     FROM cte1 c1
          FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.OrderId = c2.OrderId
     WHERE c1.Count <> c2.Count
```

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the `Orders` table contains many more orders than the `LatestOrders` table, and I don't want to find all orders that are in the `LatestOrders` table and not in the `Orders` table. What I'm trying to find is all orders that are in both tables but don't have a matching `OrderItemId` in the `LatestOrders` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you need to find rows where the `OrderId` **does** exist in `LatestOrders`, but `OrderItemId` **does not**, you can't do a simple `LEFT JOIN` and exclude `NULL` as others have suggested.  That solution will include the rows you are looking for, but will also include rows where `OrderId` isn't in `LatestOrders` at all.

The simplest way is to do two `EXISTS` checks, one that checks that the `OrderId` is in `LatestOrders` and a second that checks that the `OrderId, OrderItemId` combination **is not**.  Here is a potential query:

```
SELECT  O.*
FROM    Orders O
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LatestOrders LO WHERE O.OrderId = LO.OrderId)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LatestOrders LO WHERE O.OrderId = LO.OrderId AND O.OrderItemId = LO.OrderItemId)
```

### Example

**Orders**

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemId |
+---------+-------------+
| 5062154 |      187503 |
| 5063171 |      188697 |
| 5063670 |      189314 |
| 5063670 |      189315 | <- OrderId exists in LatestOrders but OrderItemId does not
| 5063613 |      189395 | <- OrderId doesn't exist in LatestOrders
+---------+-------------+
```

**LatestOrders**

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemId |
+---------+-------------+
| 5062154 |      187503 |
| 5063171 |      188697 |
| 5063670 |      189314 |
| 5063670 |      189417 | <- OrderId exists in Orders but OrderItemId does not
| 5063698 |      189401 | <- OrderId doesn't exist in Orders
+---------+-------------+
```

**Results**

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemId |
+---------+-------------+
| 5063670 |      189315 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Well played, +1 for explaining why that flew right over my head.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a left joiun on OrderItemId and check for null values

```
select a.OrderItemId
from Orders a 
left join LatestOrders  b on a.OrderItemId = b.OrderItemId 
where b.OrderItemId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a left join using both fields and then removing the outer nulls should do the trick.

```
SELECT 
    OrderID,
    OrederItemID
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN LatestOrders LO ON LO.OrderID=O.OrderID AND LO.OrderItemID=O.OrderItemID
WHERE
    LO.OrderID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this answer but it was not up when I started working on it.
Do a left join and test for null.

```
declare @o table(OrderId int, OrderItemId int);
insert @o values 
(5062154, 187503),
(5063171, 188697),
(5063670, 189314),
(5063670, 189315);
declare @ol table(OrderId int, OrderItemId int);
insert @ol values 
(5062154, 187503),
(5063171, 188697),
(5063670, 189314),
(5063698, 189401);

select o.* 
from @o o
left join @ol ol
  on o.OrderId     = ol.OrderId 
 and o.OrderItemId = ol.OrderItemId 
where ol.OrderId is null
```